# Documentation/List of standard preprocessing symbols

Tags: f#, symbols, preprocessor-directive

As an example, I'm using the following preprocessing directive

```
 #if COMPILED 
 let context = Sql.GetDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.[AppDB].ConnectionString)
 #else 
 let context = Sql.GetDataContext()
 #endif
```

so that I'm able to test a dll library from F# interactive, to give you an idea

```
#I @"bin\Debug"
#r @"import.dll"
#r @"FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"

#load "Library1.fs"
open SqlLib
open SqlDB

// Define your library scripting code here
let book = "My Company"
let db = DB()
db.analysts book |> Array.iter (printfn "%A")
```

because, of course, in the example above `ConfigurationManager` would not be usable from the scripting engine, so I need to implement a change at preprocessing time.

More generally, where can I find the documentation or a at least a list of all the available, standard symbols, that are already automatically defined, including `COMPILED` and so on...?

Answer (score 1):

From [Compiler directives F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-directives#conditional-compilation-directives):

> Symbols that you use in the if directive must be defined by the command line or in the project settings; there is no define preprocessor directive...
>
> When VERSION1 is defined by using the -define compiler option, the code between the #if directive and the #else directive is activated. Otherwise, the code between #else and #endif is activated.

So you can defined your own preprocessor directives when compile code. If you work with .NET Core, inside fsproj or csproj you can define these symbols as:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net40'">
    <DefineConstants>NET45</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

dotnet sends them to fsc. If you curious what symbols are defined by default, you can investigate [fsc source code](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/search?q=conditionalCompilationDefines&unscoped_q=conditionalCompilationDefines)

I found COMPILED and INTERACTIVE there.